# turning off RoundTo uses the Banker's rounding

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

It seems that when using the function RoundTo (math unit) it uses the Banker's rounding, for example my column.point = 76.5 returns 76 instead of 77. I use Lazarus 1.8.2 FPC 3.0.4

```
result:= Double(column.point * scale)//76.5; 
SetRoundMode(rmNearest);
result:= RoundTo(result,-decimalen)//76;
```

how can I turn off Banker's rounding so the rounding for 76.5 ~= 77 or alternative solutions perhaps? if decimal point is .5 the use SetRoundMode(rmup) instead? thanks guys

Comment: So you always want .5 to round up, but .49 to round down, correct? None of the documented modes provided will guarantee that, so you'll have to implement your own rounding algorithm, which is essentially `Round(X) ::= Trunc(X+0.5)`

Comment: yes, i saw that SimpleRoundTo can work aswell?

Comment: "Round up" may mean that it rounds e.g., 3.1 to 4. That's probably not what you want. That's why you may need to define your own as above.

Comment: Isn't the real problem that you are using binary floating point type for operations on decimal data?

Comment: Jeff: that is not bankers rounding. Bankers rounding rounds halves to nearest EVEN number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleRoundTo function did the trick.
Thanks all for your help.